# Sending Tracking data from Marketing Cloud to Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am sending email using journey builder, email data coming from service cloud , I need to send email tracking data back to service cloud. What is best approach to achieve this.

There was a question last year but somebody replied MC team working on it, anybody have more information regarding this.

Kind Regards